# Should all data be stored in Redis?

Tags: redis

I am building a news site. Currently, I use MySQL as main data store and Redis to maintain list of articles for a user home page feed. When users click on an article on home page, I connect to MySQL to get the main content of the articles, comments, and related stuff.

Is it best practice if I store all article data in Redis? I mean instead of connecting to MySQL to get the whole content of an article, I store the main content of articles in Redis so that the performance can be improved?

Comment: Do you mean to use Redis as your *only* data store or as your *primary* and let MySQL be the *secondary*?

Comment: MySQL is my main data store. I use Redis as viewer independent data store to improve performance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is opinion-based, so here's my opinion. Redis is primed to be used as a cache. You need to decide what to cache, and if caching is actually necessary. This depends on the scale of your app. If the articles change a lot and you do not have a huge user/visitor base, I do not think Redis is necessary at all. Remember you cannot search for stuff there. You can't go `SELECT articles WHERE author='foo'` in Redis.

If, on the other hand, you are seeing a massive increase in DB load due to to many users, you could pre-render the HTML for all the articles and put that into Redis. That would save the DB and the web server some load. But only if you already know which articles you want to display.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on the role redis is supposed to take in your case.

If it serves as a cache, you could try to store more data in redis, where possible. As long as the development overhead is small and the process doesn't introduce new sources of errors.

In case you want redis to be a primary source for your data, what it doesn't sound like in your case, you could also decide to move everything away from MySQL. With low, and "rarely" changing data, it might be worth a shot. But remember to back up the database and sync to the HDD after changes.